# MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity with a Non cached fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, mvvmcross, android-support-library

I'm following the fragment examples here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport. I'm trying to create a Non-cacheable fragment by setting the IsCacheableFragment attribute on my fragment.  However, when I do this, the ViewModel never gets set.

For example:

```
 [MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true, IsCacheableFragment =false)]
 [Register("example.droid.fragments.ExampleRecyclerViewFragment")]
public class ExampleRecyclerViewFragment : BaseFragment<ExampleRecyclerViewModel>
{...
```

will throw an error in OnCreate, because ViewModel is null

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var recyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
        if (recyclerView != null)
        {
            recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
            var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
         //ViewModel is null
        _itemSelectedToken = ViewModel.WeakSubscribe(() => ViewModel.SelectedItem,
            (sender, args) => {
                if (ViewModel.SelectedItem != null)
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity,
                        $"Selected: {ViewModel.SelectedItem.Title}",
                        ToastLength.Short).Show();
            });
         ....
```

I solved my issue by doing something similar to this [MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity refresh cached fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195393/mvxcachingfragmentcompatactivity-refresh-cached-fragment).

Should the attribute on the fragment do what I intended or is it used for something else?